# Manage Java CardLayout JPanels created with different classes

Tags: java, swing

I need a simple example of how to manage multiple JPanels (created with different classes) in one JFrame using CardLayout (or something else?). This is an illustrative example of what I need:

**Panel A**:

[image]

**Panel B**:

[image]

Example of file structures:

```
// Gui.java
public class Gui {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

// PanelA.java
public class PanelA {
    ...
    ...
    ... () {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        JButton btn = new JButtn("Show Panel B");
        pnl.add(btn);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ...
    }
}

// PanelB.java
public class PanelB {
    ...
    ...
    ... () {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        JButton btn = new JButtn("Show Panel A");
        pnl.add(btn);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I found a lot of examples doing this, but all JPanels were created in the same class with JButtons as fields so the Listener could access to them. I tried to edit those examples but with no success.
Sorry for my bad english, Thank You in advance!

Comment: The first thing to realise is that neither of the panels seen above needs to extend panel (based on the code given). **Why** do they extend `JPanel`?

Comment: There is no `extends` in the code above... There are in my answer, tho...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Gui.java:

```
public class Gui {
    ...
    JPanel cards = ne JPanel(new CardLayout());
    private void initComponetns() {
        ...
        // cards to be the container with CardLayout...
        cards.add(new PanelA(this));
        cards.add(new PanelB(this));
        ...
    }
}
```

PanelA.java

```
public class PanelA extends JPanel {
    ...
    private final Gui gui;
    PanelA(Gui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }
    ... () {
        setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        JButton btn = new JButtn("Show Panel B");
        add(btn);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ...
        gui.cards. ...
    }
}
```

PanelB.java

```
public class PanelB extends JPanel {
    ...
    private final Gui gui;
    PanelB(Gui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }
    ...
    ... () {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        JButton btn = new JButtn("Show Panel A");
        add(btn);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ...
        gui.cards. ...
    }
}
```

### Edited...

Comment: how can I use "cards" from Gui.java in the listener of PanelA/PanelB?

Comment: when I click on "button 1" (show panel b) I'm getting `NullPointerException`. what is the correct way to access to `cards` field of super class?